# Problem with swap in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, ram, swap, memory-usage

I have Ubuntu 18.04 installed on my PC which having 8GB total memory and I allowed 2GB swap space when installing Ubuntu. When in normal operation it uses about 2GB from main memory and zero of swap.

My problem is, when I'm running a memory crunching process, It will start to use swap space after exhausting all the main memory available, but when I finished memory crunching process it will keep using swap space even if the main memory available in GB's. Due to usage of swap my PC getting slow after this operation. So this will lead to restart my PC to recover from it.

Is there a way to fix this, so that I can clear swap when main memory is available? Or is it a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once swap has been addressed, some swap will typically remain used even if after having run a memory consuming operation, you revert to your "normal" use of about 2 GB. After having used your memory crunching process, much of the other processes will have been swapped to the swap memory. These will be reclaimed to RAM as they are needed again by other activities. They will remain in swap as long as they are not needed. Typically, you should see that gradually swap use decreases, and the system becomes faster again.

There is a way to get more quickly back to normal. You can immediately "flush" all processes from SWAP back to main memory by turning swap off and back on. This requires the commands:

```
sudo swapoff -a
sudo swapon -a
```

Comment: Yeah Thanks! I didn't know that..

Answer (score 1):

*TL;DR: There should be no need to reset swap, reboot or do anything in particular about this situation. It should resolve itself while you use your system normally.*

This is no permanent state. As memory pressure subsides and you start to use applications with swapped memory pages they are “un”-swapped and placed back into main memory on demand. This is a one-time thing and of course it will temporarily slow down your system and the affected applications.

Typically some swapped pages will remain swapped because they remain unused. This can happen when applications erroneously fail to relinquish resources that they no longer use or when they acquire more resources than they actually need. On a small scale this is not a bad thing or a problem from the point of view of (virtual) memory management though; secondary memory is plenty and cheap, certainly more plentiful and cheaper than main memory, so even if you had a few gigabytes of permanently swapped memory it doesn’t hurt much (except that you may need to increase the swap space a little and loose a little storage space for other purposes).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got cleared more about swap..!