# sometime system hangs for long time when much RAM used

Tags: 18.04

I have i7 CPU with 16 Gb RAM DDR3, 50 Gb for SWAP, partition is ext4.

After sometime while system runs soft that use much of memory (development IDE, virtual emulators, ...), in some moments DEEP HANGS FOR AT LEAST 30 minutes, HDD is busy (continuously working), mouse not moving (some time change cursor position after 5-10 minutes), clock time not updated. So I have to restart system instead waiting so long time.  I don't understand why this happens and why system all time not responsive. How it is possible? What is wrong? What do I need to check/change?

Comment: usually at windows system when low on RAM, it begins for small hangs, than, if amount of usable memory increase, it could hang for more, but ubuntu hangs at once for long time, than it works normally.

Comment: it could hangs whatever soft running, only because low on free RAM. same behavior in my second PC, also it was previously in Ubuntu 17.x before upgrade to 18.04.

Comment: yes, I think so it couldn't happens, but it does. so I try to figure out what is wrong. Previously the hangs appear quickly before I have setup swap-drive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem with swap in ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077507/problem-with-swap-in-ubuntu-18-04)